# IdentifierReferenceResolver: resolving at project level

Tags: c#, linq, rubberduck

One of the most important parts at the core of [rubberduck](/questions/tagged/rubberduck) is the `IdentifierReferenceResolver` class, which is responsible for resolving each declaration as the parse tree is being walked and function, member and variable calls are being encountered.

Proper scoping is the single most important concept here: when we meet an assignment to `foo`, we possibly have 20 `foo` identifier declarations, and we need to find the single `Declaration` object that's being referred to, create an `IdentifierReference` object and add it to that declaration object's `References` concurrent bag.

So that's what the `IdentifierReferenceResolver` class is doing. For context, here's a few lines of code from the main `ResolveInternal` overload:

> ```
> callee = FindLocalScopeDeclaration(identifierName, localScope, parentContext, isAssignmentTarget)
>       ?? FindModuleScopeProcedure(identifierName, localScope, accessorType, isAssignmentTarget)
>       ?? FindModuleScopeDeclaration(identifierName, localScope)
>       ?? FindProjectScopeDeclaration(identifierName, Equals(localScope, _currentScope) ? null : localScope, hasStringQualifier);
> ```

The resolver first tries to find the `Declaration` object for `identifierName` within the current (local) scope; if that doesn't work, it tries to find a procedure (member actually) in the same module that could match - otherwise `FindModuleScopeDeclaration` would find 2 matches when a property has a getter and a setter procedures. if that returns `null`, then it tries to find a match at module scope, and when all else fails, it tries to find a match at project scope - and this is where things get funky.

I had this working code:

> ```
> private Declaration FindProjectScopeDeclaration(string identifierName, Declaration localScope = null, bool hasStringQualifier = false)
> {
>     var matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn && item.IdentifierName == identifierName
>         || item.IdentifierName == identifierName + (hasStringQualifier ? "$" : string.Empty)).ToList();
>
>     if (matches.Count == 1)
>     {
>         return matches.Single();
>     }
>
>     if (localScope == null && _withBlockQualifiers.Any())
>     {
>         localScope = _withBlockQualifiers.Peek();
>     }
>
>     try
>     {
>         return matches.SingleOrDefault(item => !item.IsBuiltIn &&
>             !item.DeclarationType.HasFlag(DeclarationType.Member)
>             && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event // events can't be called outside the class they're declared in
>             && (item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public
>                 || item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global
>                 || _moduleTypes.Contains(item.DeclarationType)))
>         // todo: refactor
>         ?? matches.SingleOrDefault(item => item.IsBuiltIn 
>             && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event 
>             && ((localScope == null && item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global)
>                 || (localScope != null && (item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public || item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global) && localScope.IdentifierName == item.ParentDeclaration.IdentifierName)));
>     }
>     catch (InvalidOperationException)
>     {
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

Notice that `// todo: refactor` comment - it's been there for about as far as I can remember. And that horrible "one-liner" (*for some values of* "one-liner") `return` statement has only kept growing hair and tentacles since it was first written, and it seemed to me that extracting methods would make the logic more self-descriptive.

The method receives a `string` identifier, and uses an instance-level `_declarations` object that contains every single identifier that was picked up when the ANTLR parse tree was first walked to locate identifier *declarations*. When `localScope` is specified, it's the `Declaration` for the *type* of `foo` in `foo.Bar`. `hasStringQualifier` is only needed to pick up the built-in the string-typed versions of a number of functions, such as `Chr$`, `UCase$`, `Environ$` and others - merely working around a little limitation of the grammar/parser.

So I refactored it to this:

```
private Declaration FindProjectScopeDeclaration(string identifierName, Declaration localScope = null, bool hasStringQualifier = false)
{
    // the "$" in e.g. "UCase$" isn't picked up as part of the identifierName, so we need to add it manually:
    var matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn && item.IdentifierName == identifierName
        || item.IdentifierName == identifierName + (hasStringQualifier ? "$" : string.Empty)).ToList();

    if (matches.Count == 1)
    {
        return matches.Single();
    }

    if (localScope == null && _withBlockQualifiers.Any())
    {
        localScope = _withBlockQualifiers.Peek();
    }

    try
    {
        return matches.SingleOrDefault(IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope)
        ?? matches.SingleOrDefault(item => IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(item, localScope));
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private static bool IsPublicOrGlobal(Declaration item)
{
    return item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global
        || item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public;
}

private bool IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope(Declaration item)
{
    var isNonMemberUserDeclaration = !item.IsBuiltIn 
        && !item.DeclarationType.HasFlag(DeclarationType.Member)
        // events can't be called outside the class they're declared in, exclude them as well:
        && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event;

    // declaration is in-scope if it's public/global, or if it's a module/class:
    return isNonMemberUserDeclaration && (IsPublicOrGlobal(item) || _moduleTypes.Contains(item.DeclarationType));
}

private static bool IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(Declaration item, Declaration localScope)
{
    var isBuiltInNonEvent = item.IsBuiltIn && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event;

    // if localScope is null, we can only resolve to a global:
    // note: built-in declarations are designed that way
    var isBuiltInGlobal = localScope == null && item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global;

    // if localScope is not null, we can resolve to any public or global in that scope:
    var isInLocalScope = localScope != null && IsPublicOrGlobal(item)
        && localScope.IdentifierName == item.ParentDeclaration.IdentifierName;

    return isBuiltInNonEvent && (isBuiltInGlobal || isInLocalScope);
}
```

Is this as good as it gets? What else could be improved? Are the comments helpful, or noise? Is anything unclear or questionable?

---

For more context, the full `IdentifierReferenceResolver` class can be found [here](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/2d44cb27c88c12a14d5a9401a7066dcf4ae8617b/Rubberduck.Parsing/Symbols/IdentifierReferenceResolver.cs) (GitHub).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> try
> {
>     return matches.SingleOrDefault(IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope)
>     ?? matches.SingleOrDefault(item => IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(item, localScope));
> }
> catch (InvalidOperationException)
> {
>     return null;
> }
> ```

This doesn't look like an appropriate use of `try-catch`, but one you've been forced into by the semantics of `SingleOrDefault`. In fact, I'm not sure the behaviour is what you want -- if two or more elements of `matches` satisfy `IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope` then an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, and we never check if any elements satisfy `IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope`.

I think what you want is to write a method

```
TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
        TSource defaultValue)
```

that returns

- `defaultValue` if there are 0 elements satisfying `predicate`,
- `defaultValue` if there are 2+ elements satisfying `predicate`,
- The only matching element, otherwise.

With this method, we can write instead

```
return matches.SingleOrDefault(IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope, null)
    ?? matches.SingleOrDefault(item => IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(item, localScope), null);
```

Comment: You've just fixed a bug!

Answer (score 3):

**FindProjectScopeDeclaration**

> ```
> var matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn && item.IdentifierName == identifierName
>     || item.IdentifierName == identifierName + (hasStringQualifier ? "$" : string.Empty)).ToList();
> ```

Here, if `hastStringQualifier` would be false this will be evaluated to

> ```
> var matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn && item.IdentifierName == identifierName
>     || item.IdentifierName == identifierName).ToList();
> ```

So basically you don't care at all wether `item.IsBuiltIn` or not.

If you care but coded this a little bit lazy, a better way would be to split this into two queries like so

```
List<Declaration> matches;
if (hasStringQualifier)
{
    identifierName = identifierName  + "$";
    matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => item.IdentifierName == identifierName).ToList();
}
else
{
    matches = _declarations.Items.Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn && item.IdentifierName == identifierName).ToList();
}
```

---

> ```
> if (matches.Count == 1)
> {
>     return matches.Single();
> }
> ```

You should access the `List<T>` item by its index instead of using the `Single()` extension method.

---

> ```
> if (localScope == null && _withBlockQualifiers.Any())
> {
>     localScope = _withBlockQualifiers.Peek();
> }
> ```

From the sources I could see that `withBlockQualifiers` is a `Stack<T>` which has a `Count` property which you should use instead of `Any()`.

Although `Any()` would use this property too, some casts and nullchecks will be added hence it has some performance costs. In addition you just should prefer builtin methods and properties over extension methods.

---

> ```
> private static bool IsPublicOrGlobal(Declaration item)
> {
>     return item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global
>         || item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public;
> }
> ```

here I would prefer to have an `Accessibility` enum parameter method argument to make it more clear and easier to read.

---

> ```
> private bool IsUserDeclarationInProjectScope(Declaration item)
> {
>     var isNonMemberUserDeclaration = !item.IsBuiltIn 
>         && !item.DeclarationType.HasFlag(DeclarationType.Member)
>         // events can't be called outside the class they're declared in, exclude them as well:
>         && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event;
>
>     // declaration is in-scope if it's public/global, or if it's a module/class:
>     return isNonMemberUserDeclaration && (IsPublicOrGlobal(item) || _moduleTypes.Contains(item.DeclarationType));
> }
> ```

using a comment between boolean operators is ugly and makes this almost unreadable.

---

> ```
> private static bool IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(Declaration item, Declaration localScope)
> {
>     var isBuiltInNonEvent = item.IsBuiltIn && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event;
>
>     // if localScope is null, we can only resolve to a global:
>     // note: built-in declarations are designed that way
>     var isBuiltInGlobal = localScope == null && item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global;
>
>     // if localScope is not null, we can resolve to any public or global in that scope:
>     var isInLocalScope = localScope != null && IsPublicOrGlobal(item)
>         && localScope.IdentifierName == item.ParentDeclaration.IdentifierName;
>
>     return isBuiltInNonEvent && (isBuiltInGlobal || isInLocalScope);
> }
> ```

here you should return early if `isBuiltInNonEvent == false` or if  `isBuiltInGlobal == true` in which case we can omit the check for `localScope != null`. For readability I would leave the variables like they are although they could be omitted.

```
private static bool IsBuiltInDeclarationInScope(Declaration item, Declaration localScope)
{
    var isBuiltInNonEvent = item.IsBuiltIn && item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Event;
    if (!isBuiltInNonEvent) { return false; }

    // if localScope is null, we can only resolve to a global:
    // note: built-in declarations are designed that way
    var isBuiltInGlobal = localScope == null && item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Global;
    if (isBuiltInGlobal) { return true; }

    // if localScope is not null, we can resolve to any public or global in that scope:
    var isInLocalScope = IsPublicOrGlobal(item)
        && localScope.IdentifierName == item.ParentDeclaration.IdentifierName;

    return isInLocalScope;
}
```

Comment: *So basically you don't care at all wether item.IsBuiltIn or not.* oh wow, this has unforeseen implications elsewhere: `Function Foo$()` actually breaks the *grammar*, and is legal VBA! Yet another grammar bug solved! Every time I think I know all the issues this grammar has, I get a new surprise...